# $S_1, S_2,...,S_k$ are subsets of $V$ such that, prove that $V = \operatorname{span}\{S_1\} + \dotsb + \operatorname{span}\{S_k\}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

> If $x_1,...,x_k$ is a basis for a vector space $V$, and $S_1, S_2,...,S_k$ are subsets of $V$ such that $x_i \in S_i$ for all $i$, prove that $V = \operatorname{span}\{S_1\} + \operatorname{span}\{S_2\} +\dotsb + \operatorname{span}\{S_k\}$.

**My Attempt**

Since $x_i\in \operatorname{span}\{S_i\}$, for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$ then $cx_i \in \operatorname{span}\{S_i\}$. This makes AT MINIMAL $\operatorname{span}\{x_i,...,x_k\} = V \subseteq \operatorname{span}\{S_1\} + \operatorname{span}\{S_2\} +\dotsb + \operatorname{span}\{S_k\}$. Furthermore, it is clear that $\operatorname{span}\{S_1\} + \operatorname{span}\{S_2\} +\dotsb + \operatorname{span}\{S_k\} \subseteq V$

QED

Comment: It might be helpful to work a little closer to the definitions and step further away from "set arithmetic." Let $v$ be an element of $V$. Because $\{x_i\}$ is a basis for $V$, there are scalars $\{a_i\}$ for which $\sum_i a_i x_i = v$. Because $x_i \in S_i$ for all $i$, and from the definition of $\text{span}$, each vector $a_i x_i$ is in $\text{span} (S_i)$. Etc. Etc.

Answer (score 1):

In my calculation $A+B=\{a+b | a\in A, b\in B\}$. Let $v \in V$, then $v=\sum_{i=1}^k c_ix_i$, for some scalers $c_i$'s. By definition $c_ix_i \in span\{S_i\}$. So $v=\sum_{i=1}^k c_ix_i \in \sum_{i=1}^k span\{S_i\}\Rightarrow V \subseteq \sum_{i=1}^k span\{S_i\}$, the other side is obvious. Combining we get the desired result.